# Мне стало плохо – да так, что не дай Бог.

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, выражение "**что не дай Бог**" несет какую-нибудь синтаксическую функцию? Каков сам тип всего предложения?

спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Мне стало плохо – да так (плохо), что не дай бог!**

Подобные конструкции составлены **по следующей общей схеме**: Это так хорошо, что дай бог каждому. Это так плохо, что не дай бог никому. Они имеют структуру **СПП с двойным значением: придаточное степени и следствия**. Общая схема может перестраиваться или сокращаться. К примеру, в приведенном варианте указательное слово ТАК  и придаточное оформлены в виде присоединительной конструкции. Мне стало плохо – да так, что не дай бог.  **Другие возможные варианты:** Мне стало так  плохо, что не дай бог. Мне  так  стало плохо – не приведи бог.

**Для справок**

Устойчивые выражения "не дай бог, не приведи бог, избави (сохрани, упаси) бог" используются **в значении междометий, определяющих отрицательную оценку события или выражающих чувства опасения** по поводу негативных последствий чего-либо.  Устойчивые выражения такого вида используются **в различных конструкциях**: иногда на правах предложения, иногда в значении одного слова или в виде попутного замечания. Они   могут **обособляться (запятыми или тире) или не обособляться,** например: Не приведи бог (=нежелательно) с ним встретиться . Сестра-хозяйка пришла! **Не дай бог** (=вдруг) увидит! Еще простудится, **не дай бог** (=вдруг) , заболеет, сляжет, а ей работать надо. Уж **так** его изуродовали – **не приведи бог!**